# OS X permissions when setting up TypeScript

Tags: macos, permissions, node.js

I'm having some issues today setting up type script. Heres what I have done...

```
$ npm install -g typescript
*Package Downloaded
```

Open Terminal and run

```
$ tsc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/tsc: Permission denied
$ sudo tsc 
sudo: tsc: command not found
```

Any suggestions on whats gone wrong here?

As per questions below

```
Liams-MacBook-Pro:~ Liam$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/tsc

-rw-r--r--@ 1 Liam  staff  679220 18 May 13:03 /usr/local/bin/tsc
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/tsc` say?

Comment: @slhck Updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is – for some reason – not marked as executable. To change this, simply run:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tsc
```

If this is an ongoing problem with things you install through `npm`, consider filing a bug report on [their GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues).